# Image in canvas background, Python

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter

I want to put my own image in the background of the canvas.
I made this code:

```
size = (800,600)
im = Image.new('RGB',size)
pix = im.load()
for i in range(size[0]):
    for j in range(size[1]):
        pix[i,j] = (100,100,100) 
im.save('ima5.png')

im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(width=Width, height=Height, bg=im2)
```

I've this error: `_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "pyimage1"`, I know it's why the image haven't the format expected by the canvas.
How to put im2 as background of the canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bg/background attribute requires a color, not an image. To use an image as the background, use the `create_image` method of the canvas:

```
import Image, ImageTk, Tkinter

im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("<path\\to\\image.jpg-ect>").resize((800,600)))
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(Parent, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack() #place(), etc.
Canvas_Image = canvas.create_image(0,0 image=im, anchor="nw")
```